# How can I prevent a window from showing background colouring

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I have an application which pops up a NSTextView in its main window.

Under Yosemite this shows the main window background colouring, which is very distracting.
If users select Reduce transparency it works as before.

How can I prevent this view from showing background colouring?

---

The `NSTextView` uses `addSubView` to add itself to the enclosing view.
I have tried subclassing and returning `opaque` `YES`, but can't seem to find any way of preventing other views showing through.

I guess I could remove the existing views, but this seems a little drastic.

Any suggestions?